# Sort out whose who are still working by date

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, date

I have an Excel file with 4 columns: **Name, Staff_No, Date_Joined, Date_Left**.
My boss wants to know those who are still working.
The output should look: **Name, Staff_No, Date_Joined**.
Any idea for the Excel formula? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's always a good idea to post some sample data with desired output, so we can better understand your problem. Just having your description I'd say you need to filter your table to include only rows where date_left is blank.

Answer (score 0):

*This solves the issue:*

[image]

**N.B.**

- If you are using older version of Excel then use this array CSE
  formula in cell AE15.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(AE$2:AE$6, SMALL(IF($AH$2:$AH$6="", ROW($AH$2:$AH$6)-ROW($AH$2)+1), ROW(1:1))),"" )}`
  ```
- *Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**,and fill Right then Down.*
- If using higher version like 2021 or 365 the you may use this dynamic
  array function in cell AE10.

  `=FILTER($AE$2:$AG$6,$AH$2:$AH$6="","No Data")`
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Range and go to Data- From Table/Range:
[image]

Under the Power Query Editor- filter the Date_Left column- select null:
[image]

Right click the Date_Left column and select Remove- then Close & Load:
[image]
[image]